# VIM + screen on remote (ssh) linux machine

Tags: bash, vim, gnu-screen

The problem happens with my text in vim when I'm working inside of `screen`
this is my `.screenrc` file

```
defshell -bash
startup_message off
term screen-256color
```

and this is what I can see in my terminal (check on letters position) when I'm moving caret up and down between lines
[image]

Comment: It seems related to `$TERM`, which should be set to `screen-256color`. Check this answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139075/tmux-ncurses-apps-are-displayed-wrong-with-garbage-and-so-on

Comment: @DmitryFrank it was before `xterm-256color` and I've tried to set it to suggested `screen-256color` but it became only worse :(

Answer (score 0):

The apparent symptom is characters moving unexpectedly about (left/right).

It is likely either (a) locale mismatch or (b) mismatch between the actual terminal and the `TERM` values.  The difference in behavior for *that* between `xterm` and `xterm-256color` would be irrelevant.  (Those would only affect vim's use of colors).

A locale mismatch could be diagnosed by running the `locale` program on the locale system and on the remote one.  For instance, if one reports

```
LANG=en_US
LC_CTYPE=en_US
LC_ALL=en_US
```

while the other says

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

you would have a problem, because programs (such as vim) which count characters to find the number of columns — and position on the screen — can be confused by the extra bytes used for UTF-8 encoding, and count those as extra columns.

For mismatches in `TERM`, it is harder to pinpoint (depends upon knowing what actual terminal is used, and the terminal descriptions involved).

Comment: Hey @thomas it's interesting idea about locale mismatch. What should I check? Could clarify bit?